# Troubles importing Gradle project to Eclipse: Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

The thing is that I'm struggling to import a Gradle project to Eclipse and it's really pissing me off. It's like it can't be recognized as a project since there's no way to edit the buildpath. I don't have any idea what this is about. I've been told about the JDBC driver, about the build path, about everything...but I haven't been able to fix it so far. The console throws the error:

***Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package jdk.internal.jrtfs in both module jrt.fs and module java.base***

By the way: the project is about connecting Eclipse to a DB using PostgreSQL.

I'm attaching a couple of screenshots:

[image]

And the one showing there's no buildpath options:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you import it?

Comment: Hi! File -> Import -> Existing Gradle Project -> I selected the folder -> Finish